# Excel WPF Addin Drag Drop Error

Tags: wpf, excel, add-in

I created a Sidebar in Excel using WPF, and trying to drag some some objects from the WPF Pane to the spreadsheet. The Application object in WPF is null. Please guide me how to Achieve this Drag-Drop simple text from WPF Excel Addin to The spreadsheet.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this problem is well explained in [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) section "**Hosting WPF Content in a Microsoft Win32 Window**"

This will be for any one who wants to get the power of WPF to build excel addins.